# Unable to get the value from Promise.allSettled in NodeJs 12 with Typescript 3.8.3 version

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-promise

I am learning NodeJs 12 with `Promise.allSettled()` function and its usage.
I have written the following code. I am able to print the status in the console but unable to print the value as it is giving compilation issue.

```
        const p1 = Promise.resolve(50);
        const p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
            setTimeout(reject, 100, 'geek'));
        const prm = [p1, p2];

        Promise.allSettled(prm).
        then((results) => results.forEach((result) =>
            console.log(result.status,result.value)));
```

I am getting the following compilation issue.
[image]

I provide below the tsconfig.json.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": ["es6","esnext", "dom"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "typeRoots": [ "./types", "./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["**/__tests__/*"]
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You might want something like this:

```
  Promise.allSettled(prm).
    then((results) => results.forEach(result => {
       if (result.status === 'fulfilled') {
         console.log(result.status,result.value);
       } else {
         console.log(result.status,result.reason);
       }
    });
```

`value` only exists if the status is fulfilled, but it doesn't cover cases where one of the promises had an error.

Comment: This is working. Thank you Sir. I got to know this new concept. it is bit different from Promis.all(). +1 and accepted the answer.

Comment: Sir, can I avoid this hard coding 'fulfilled'?

Comment: Yes, you could create a constant elsewhere and give it the value `fulfilled`.

Comment: However, I wouldn't worry too much about this. Most reasons to avoid 'hard coding' doesn't really apply here. Notice that if you attempt to misspell the word `fulfilled`, typescript will give you an error.

Comment: I was thinking to use enum type like Promise.FULFILLED, something like this.

Comment: I understand, but this basically works the same way. (but better). `status` is not type `string`, it's type `'fulfilled' | 'rejected'`, so you already get the same advantages of something like an enum.

Answer (score 11):

[Using typeguards to correctly type `PromiseSettledResult` like in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63120224) but without creating a specific `isFullfilled` function and using `filter` + `map`

```js
const promises = [
  Promise.reject("Error"),
  Promise.resolve(42),
  Promise.reject("Another error")
]
const results = await Promise.allSettled(promises)
const successes = results
  .filter((x): x is PromiseFulfilledResult<number> => x.status === "fulfilled")
  .map(x => x.value)
const failures: any[] = results
  .filter((x): x is PromiseRejectedResult => x.status === "rejected")
  .map(x => x.reason)
```

I believe the typing system is flexible enough to be extended to correctly type

```js
const successes = results
  .filter(x => x.status === "fulfilled")
  .map(x => x.value)
const failures = results
  .filter(x => x.status === "rejected")
  .map(x => x.reason)
```

but I wasn't able to figure that out myself.

Answer (score 10):

If one of the promises will be rejected, your object will have no value. To warn you about this possibility, TypeScript uses this type:

[image]

So, to get value from the result you should use [guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types)

```
const isFilled = <T extends {}>(v: PromiseSettledResult<T>): v is PromiseFulfilledResult<T> => v.status === 'fulfilled';

Promise.allSettled(prm).then((results) => results.forEach((result) =>
    console.log(result.status, isFilled(result) ? result.value : result.status)));
```

or to cast it yourself

```
Promise.allSettled(prm).then((results) => results.forEach((result) =>
    console.log(result.status, (result as PromiseFulfilledResult<any>).value)));
```

Comment: Sir, I am able to print result.status, but result.value gives compilation issue. Should I always write like this to get the value always?

Comment: No, just add a guard like in the second example. It will ensure that promise filled and help s TypeScript with types

Comment: I tried to copy, it is also working. +1 from my side. First answer looks more good to me. Still I thank you for the asnwer.

Comment: The good thing about the 2nd approach is that you have to write check only once for all promises you need.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems here.

### first

The second promise you create is of type `Promise<unknown>` because typescript cannot infer its underlying type.

When you create an array with the two promises, `unknown` "swallows" everything and you are left with an array of type `Promise<unknown>[]`.

If you type `p2` like this:

```
const p2 = new Promise<number>((resolve, reject) =>
  setTimeout(reject, 100, 'geek'));
```

you won't have this problem.

### second

You probably have to do something like this for typescript to know if the promise was a success or not:

```
Promise.all(prm).then((results) =>
  results.forEach((result) => {
    if (result.status === "fulfilled") {
      console.log("fulfilled", result.value);
    } else {
      console.log("rejected", result.reason);
    }
  })
);
```